# How to get Font style depending on Font Name

Tags: jquery, fonts

I am fetching installed font names from local machine(client Machine) using Jquery.

How can I get font style(italic, bold etc) according to font names.

Comment: And what do you exactly try to accomplish? Get the available font styles for the specific font from the machine itself or set a font style depending on the font in css?

Comment: Yes Font style for the specific fonts. Is there any way? I have googled it but no luck... Thanks..

Comment: Is there any way to get the available font styles(italic,bold etc.) for the specific font?